# parsing json file not show data

Tags: android

Images will not display when parsing array from json file. Values inside `JSONArray school2 = school.getJSONArray("contains");` don't display on screen, am I using the correct method?

I am debugging values shown at this stage: `Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));`  Debugging tells me it is necessary to give id for each element in array.

```
{
  "status":1,
  "message":"",
  "data":
  {
    "entree":
    {
      "id":32,
      "name":"Cheese Burger",
      "description":"Lorem ipsum d dolore.",
      "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/images\/android\/cheese-burger.png",
      "contains":
      [
        {
          "name":"Cheese",
          "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/images\/android\/cheese1.png"
        },
        {
          "name":"Tomato",
          "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/images\/android\/tomato.png"
        },
        {
          "name":"Bread",
          "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/images\/android\/bread.png"
        }
      ],
    "nutritions":
    {
      "Calories":"150",
      "Carbohidrates":"16g"
    }
  }
}





JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);
message = json2.getString("message");
status = json2.getString("status");

if (status.equals("1")) {           
  JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
  JSONObject school = data.getJSONObject("entree");
  txt1.setText(school.getString("name"));
  // txt2.setText(school.getString("name"));
  txt3.setText(school.getString("description"));
  String url1 = school.getString("image");

  imgLoader.DisplayImage(url1, img1);
  JSONArray school2 = school.getJSONArray("contains");


  for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject   object = school2.getJSONObject(i);
   \\Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("id")));
   Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
   Category_image.add(object.getString("image"));
   listview.setAdapter(cla);
  }
}
```

Comment: why not use GSON, it is sim-official from google. I just give you the suggestion. It's better than manual parsing.

Comment: Make sure the image exists on the server. Try pasting the url in browser

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Jackson JSON or GSON parsing library and make POJOs to deserialize to.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find where you set Image for ImageView.

I think the image is no shown because the way you set image is failed.

When you get image from a link: (Example: http://domain.com/image.jpg)

You should take along time to get it.

Please use **AsyncTask** or **Thread** to do it. When you download completed image from your link, you will notify to **MainThread** which will update **UI** (In this case is set Image into ImageView)

P/S: After get Image from url, you can Parse to Bitmap